# How to use async await properly

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

i am trying to save/update some data into my firestore document.I have implemented it successfully with out any problem.To save data i am using an async function.But i am not much familiar with async functions or promises.
i have posting my code below and my question is, am i implementing the function properly or not? Is this the correct way to implement updation/creation using async function.?

Thanks in advance

Here is my code;

**edit_menu.ts**

```
 async onSaveClick() {
try {
  this.modifyService.
    updateLocationWiseMenuData(this.data.id, this.valueArray)
    .then(error => {
      console.log(error);
    }).catch(eror => {
      console.log(eror)
    })
}
catch (error) {
  throw error
}
```

}

**service.ts**

```
  async updateLocationWiseMenuData(id: string, array: any[]) {
try {

  if (id && array.length) {
    for (const i of array) {
      if (i.defaultPrice) {
        await this.afs.collection(`Locations/${id}/menuList`).doc(`${i.id}`).update({
          defaultPrice: i.defaultPrice
        })
      }
      if (i.hasOwnProperty('isAvailable')) {
        await this.afs.collection(`Locations/${id}/menuList`).doc(`${i.id}`).update({
          isAvailable: i.isAvailable
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
catch (error) {
  throw error
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what exactly it's supposed to do, it's not really easy to say whether or not it's correct.

I will say that it's not really meaningful to catch an error, then immediately rethrow it.  Just let it throw on its own and make the caller deal with it.

Also, this doesn't make sense:

```
.then(error => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

`then()` is for processing succesful results, not handling errors.

Comment: Stevension, Thanks for your quick replay , i know that then()  is processing successful result.I think an async function is a better way to handle promises;  According to my code edit_menu() not need to be an async function and only updateLocationWiseMenu() need to be async function; if my conclusion is incorrect please rectify it

Answer (score 0):

Async function is just a different syntax. Here is the code without async/await.

```
onSaveClick() {
  return this.modifyService.updateLocationWiseMenuData(this.data.id, this.valueArray)
    .then(success => {
      console.log(success);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
}
```

with async/await

```
async onSaveClick() {
  try {
    const success = await this.modifyService.updateLocationWiseMenuData(this.data.id, this.valueArray);
    console.log(success);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Both functions return a promise.

Comment: thank you for your replay .Can you please tell me the exact difference between async function and a normal function.?

Comment: No difference except the syntax.